# Check if user is already created in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy

How to check if user is already created in Jenkins on Groovy?

I am using this script for automatic creation of admin user https://github.com/foxylion/docker-jenkins/blob/master/docker-images/master/default-user.groovy but unfortunately it launches each time when docker container (with it) restarts. Consequently I lose my other manually created users in Jenkins GUI.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like getSecurityRealm() will return an impl that will include HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm ... is so this looks like it will work:

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*
import org.acegisecurity.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException

def env = System.getenv()

def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
jenkins.setSecurityRealm(new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false))
jenkins.setAuthorizationStrategy(new GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy())

def user = null;
try {

  jenkins.getSecurityRealm().loadUserByUsername(env.JENKINS_USER);

} catch (UsernameNotFoundExceoption n) {
  user = jenkins.getSecurityRealm().createAccount(env.JENKINS_USER, env.JENKINS_PASS)
  user.save()

  jenkins.getAuthorizationStrategy().add(Jenkins.ADMINISTER, env.JENKINS_USER)
  jenkins.save()
} catch (org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException d) {
   /// log
}
```